# Utilizando o fetch api

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando utilizar o fetch para consumir os dados de uma api, porém ao tentar acessar alguns atributos do objeto, está dando UNDEFINED:

```
const url = 'https://api.sheety.co/30b6e400-9023-4a15-8e6c-16aa4e3b1e72';

fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
    const dados = JSON.stringify(result);
    // console.log(response.name);


    document.getElementById('wrap').innerHTML = dados.name;
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
  })
```

Como está sendo renderizado o html:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro lugar, está transformando em string um objeto, então não pode acessar as propriedades dele se foi convertido para uma string (`dados.name` por exemplo).

Segundo, o resulta é uma array, então precisa de um índice (`result[0] por exemplo) ou fazer uma iteração com o objeto (for, foreach, etc).

```js
const url = 'https://api.sheety.co/30b6e400-9023-4a15-8e6c-16aa4e3b1e72';

fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
    const dados = JSON.stringify(result);
    // console.log(response.name);

    // aqui os dados em formato string
    document.getElementById('wrap').innerHTML = dados;
    // aqui o valor de name, como é um array, o valor do primeiro elemento
    document.getElementById('valor').innerHTML = result[0].name;
    // aqui, todos os names:
    result.forEach(function(element) {
       document.getElementById('todosValores').innerHTML += "<img src='" + element.photo + "'>" +  element.name + "<br/>";
    });
    
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
  })
```

```css
div {
   border: solid 1px #000;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 2px;
   padding: 5px;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<div id="valor">
</div>

<div id="todosValores">
</div>

<div id="wrap">
</div>
```

Comment: Tem necessidade de transformar em string?

Comment: não, coloquei no código apenas para exemplificar, o `result` já vem pronto pra ser usado :)

Comment: Eu fazendo um for, pq aparece somente um nome?   for(const dados of result) {
    console.log(dados.name);
    
    document.getElementById('wrap').innerHTML = dados.name;
  }

Comment: veja o exemplo que coloquei com `foreach`

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado!